# PostGIS: Find closest geometry to given point

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, openlayers, geospatial, postgis

Say I have a number of geometries in my databases.  I would like to create a function within PostgreSQL whereby I can pass in a lat/long and have it return the closest geometries by distance (linear, and by road) for a given radius.

I am a newbie to this, so any advice is appreciated.

I am running the following versions:

- PostgreSQL: 9.2
- PostGIS: 2.0

Here is the schema:

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for "cities-usa"
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "cities-usa";
CREATE TABLE "cities-usa" (
"gid" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"cities-usa_gid_seq"'::regclass),
"st_fips" varchar(4),
"sfips" varchar(2),
"county_fip" varchar(4),
"cfips" varchar(4),
"pl_fips" varchar(7),
"id" varchar(20),
"name" varchar(39),
"elevation" varchar(60),
"pop_1990" numeric,
"population" varchar(30),
"st" varchar(6),
"state" varchar(16),
"warngenlev" varchar(16),
"warngentyp" varchar(16),
"watch_warn" varchar(3),
"zwatch_war" float8,
"prog_disc" int4,
"zprog_disc" float8,
"comboflag" float8,
"land_water" varchar(16),
"recnum" float8,
"lon" float8,
"lat" float8,
"geom" "geometry"
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "cities-usa" OWNER TO "postgres";

-- ----------------------------
--  Primary key structure for table "cities-usa"
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "cities-usa" ADD CONSTRAINT "cities-usa_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("gid") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL and PostGIS versions? Some info about your database schema? Details, please.

Comment: For schema, I have a table of US cities, with fields including gid (int4),st_fips (varchar(4), county_fip (varchar(4) cfips varchar(4),pl_fips varchar(7),id varchar(20),name varchar(39),elevation varchar(60),pop_1990 numeric,population varchar(30),st varchar(6),state varchar(16),warngenlev varchar(16),warngentyp varchar(16),watch_warn varchar(3),zwatch_war float8,prog_disc int4,zprog_disc float8,comboflag float8,land_water varchar(16),recnum float8,lon float8,lat float8,geom geometry.

Comment: @craig-ringer, I'm looking to create a function of sorts, where I can call it like WhatAmINear(lat, long, radius, num) and have it return the closest num cities for the given radius.  For example, if I call it as WhatAmINear(lat1, lon1, 100, 5), it would return the 5 closest cities to my location within a 100 mile radius.  If less than 5 are within that range, only return those ones.

Comment: You don't appear to have read the first part of my comment. **Versions please**. Edit your question and add the schema you added in a comment, your versions, and any other info you can think of that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks, @craig-ringer.  I did initially put in the versions yesterday, but had issues saving.  I must have accidentally deleted them.  The versions and SQL are posted.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4):

The logic can be wrapped into a function, but I'd recommend using queries to test out the logic. The difficulties you will encounter are with linear distances (miles) combined with angular coordinates (degrees of latitude and longitude). Also the geometry type specified above does not have an SRID or geometry type. I'm guessing it should be `geometry(Point,4326)`.

There are a few strategies you can try, such as using the `geography` type, which automagically uses metres for functions like `ST_Distance`, or `ST_DWithin`. The example below just uses `ST_Distance_Sphere` with a conversion from miles to metres to get you going. Or, if you need performance, you can try the `<->` function for an [indexed nearest neighbour search](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/).

Here is something you can try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WhatAmINear(lat float8, lon float8,
                                       radius_mi float8, num int DEFAULT 10)
    RETURNS SETOF "cities-usa" AS
$body$
SELECT *
FROM "cities-usa"
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(geom, ST_MakePoint(lon, lat)) <= radius_mi * 1609.34
LIMIT num;
$body$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

And then:

```
SELECT WhatAmINear(44.9, -93.1, 100);
```